# Angular Rxjs Observable items count doubles on subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm creating an observable using an array. When I call subscribe method its length becomes doubles.

ie. if array has 3 items after subscribe it becomes 6 by duplicating same items.

I'm also using async pipe to list down items in html.

Please check the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/X6O84tUJZWraoHiridfW) example

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
 <div>
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let data of obs|async">
      {{data.name}}
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 `
 })

export class App  implements OnInit{

obs: Observable<any>;

arr = [{
   name: 'name1',
   age: 26
  }, {
   name: 'name2',
   age: 27
  }, {
   name: 'name3',
  age: 28
  }];

  constructor() {

  }
  ngOnInit() {

   this.obs = Observable.from(this.arr).toArray()


   this.obs.subscribe(res => {

    console.log(res)
   })
  }
}
```

Output :

- name1
- name2
- name3
- name1
- name2
- name3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a JSFiddle, this is working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/dcuLggwa/1/

I'm not sure why you are using: `this.obs = Observable.from(this.arr).toArray()` ?
You can use : `this.obs = Observable.of(this.arr)`, which results in the same behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/dcuLggwa/2/

I've updated the plunkr to use `Observable.of` instead of `Observable.from(...).toArray()` and it's working fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/vaMK6G5AxCSs2kCIJ2h8?p=preview

**The difference between `Observable.from(...).toArray()` and `Observable.of`:**

`Observable.from` emits every item from the array seperatly, `toArray` wait until the observable completes and then emits all the items (which are emitted seperatly) as an array. So basicly you start with an array, split it into seperate items and combine it again in an array.

`Observable.of` creates an Observable which emits the item being passed to the `of()` operator.

Comment: Thanks.. using  Observable.of fixed the problem.